# Listing modifiers with 〜であり

Tags: grammar, translation, copula

Taken from an educational book with parallel English literal translation. The original work is Mishima's "Patriotism".

> 麗子は良人の親友であり、たびたびこの家へも遊びに来た元気な青年将校の顔を思い浮べた。
>
> Reiko recalled the faces of the cheerful young officers who were such dear friends of her husband and had often paid social visits to the house.

What I'm having trouble with is the copula:

麗子は良人の親友**であり**、たびたびこの家へも遊びに来た元気な青年将校の顔を思い浮べた。

With that translation, I'd expect the sentence to look like:

麗子は良人の**親友**、たびたびこの家へも遊びに来た元気な青年将校の**顔**を思い浮べた。

Where relationship between 親友 and 顔 is copulative and the sentence becomes

麗子はXを思い浮べた。 Reiko recalled X (the noun phrase that describes the officers).

In other words, I am very confused about the original sentence's grammar and looking for an explanation how it turns into what it was translated into in the educational text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it as

> 麗子は[{(良人の親友であり、)(たびたびこの家へも遊びに来た)(元気な)青年将校}の顔]を思い浮べた。

「良人の親友であり*」「たびたびこの家へも遊びに来た」 and 「元気な」 all modify 「青年将校」.

*であり is the continuative form of である.

(良人の親友である)青年将校
-> (良人の親友であり、)(たびたびこの家にも遊びに来た)青年将校
or, (良人の親友で*、)(たびたびこの家にも遊びに来た)青年将校
*であり sounds more literary than で.

eg.
(かわいい)女の子 -> (かわいくて)(優しい)女の子
(きれいな)お姉さん -> (きれいで)(優しい)お姉さん
(医者である)父 -> (医者であり、)(教師でもある)父 or (医者で、)(教師でもある)父