# How do you formulate the 連用中止 with 形容動詞 (な adjectives) and 名詞 (nouns)?

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

According to my textbook,  verb and i-adjective sentences can be chained with the 連用中止【れんようちゅうし】 form like this:

[image]

Later on, I came across this exercise where I'm required to replace the adjectives' endings by the corresponding 連用中止. But I do not know how to turn 静かで into 連用中止 in the following sentence:

[image]

> 北海道【ほっかいどう】の7月の海は、深【ふか】**く、**青【あお】**く、**静【しず】か **___、**絵のように美しかった。

Is this feasible? What about sentences that end with a noun?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot omit で after 静か. As your textbook clearly says, this grammar is about verbs and ***i***-adjectives.

> 北海道の7月の海は、深く、青く、静か**で**、絵のように美しかった。

See: [いAdjective. difference between くて and く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3439/5010)

**EDIT:** You can also use copula-like である and say "深く、青く、静か**であり**、絵のように美しかった", too.

---

You may see two na-adjectives connected without a particle ("簡単、便利なチャットアプリ" instead of "簡単で便利なチャットアプリ"), but this is another story.

Comment: I see. My intent typing 静か____ was not to ask whether I can omit で or not, but to ask if I can place something there ____ that works similarly for the case of なadjectives. Maybe something along the lines of 「…青く、静か**であり**、絵のように美しかった」? I am not sure if your answer just points out that omitting で is not possible or you actually want to say that 静かで is the _only_ possible option. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but 静かであり sounds completely unnatural to me in this context. Also, note that what you are suggesting would involve substituting a shorter, simpler form for 深くて and 青くて, while substituting a longer, more complex form for 静かで. In that sense, you'd be making the terms less parallel, rather than more so.

Comment: Please take a look to [this entry](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/12/06/jlptn3-grammar-renyoochuushi/%3Famp%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwilptW4qIXiAhXGDGMBHR8hBSkQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0mm49t3Mlc6VGe1uLfHLf8&ampcf=1) and  [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24639/32952). Thank you for your thoughts on this.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with less parallel? I mean, to me くて、くて sounds more natural than く、く、 just because I'm used to the former construction, but at the end, both are valid. I don't see why it should'nt be the case with で and であり (provided both are valid, which I'm not sure).

Comment: である conjugates like a verb, and "深く、青く、静かであり" sounds completely natural to me. It's stiffer and more bookish than "深くて、青くて、静かで".