# Please explain the meaning of 作り

Tags: verbs

In Tobira Chapter 13 Grammar; one of the examples is
彼は20代で会社を作り、30代で、大金持ちになった。

What is 作り? What is the form of this verb? I cannot find anything on the web. It is a infinitive form of 作る? How can you use infinite form in a sentence?

Comment: Pardon my incredulity, but you can't find *anything* about 作り?

Comment: You should be able to find _something_ about 作り.  As a hint: this is a conjugation of the verb 作【つく】る.  Please try looking that up and if you're still confused, please come back and edit your question post here to specifically ask what it is that you find confusing.  :)

Comment: Picture in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67999/45489) should answer your question.

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/9831

Comment: Got it. Thank you to sundowner and Chocolate.