# Can someone explain how で、だから works here diffrenttly than だ。だから?

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

> くまは成熟したくまで、だからとても大きい。

I always see this construct as ...だ。だから never have i ever saw it used like this tried to search about it but could not find any  thing useful .
How is this で、だから different than だ。だから ?

Comment: The で is 連用形 of だ. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67999/45489

Comment: Is there any significance between で、だから andだ。だから

Comment: No. But not cutting the sentence is more natural mainly because it is short and the subject is unchanged.