# What does ばかりで in "愉快な仲間ばかりで頼もしいぜ" mean

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, phrases

> 愉快な仲間**ばかりで**頼もしいぜ

I can not understand the ばかりで in this sentence. Are ばかり and で stand together or both of them stand alone?

Answer (score 0):

[ばかり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A8%B1%E3%82%8A/#jn-174835) is a particle, so ばかり and で stand alone in the sense that it is not a form of ばかりだ (there is no such na-adjective).

- 愉快な仲間ばかりだ All my companions are cheerful
- 頼もしい I feel confident/assured

だ is the standard auxiliary verb for assertion and is transformed into its 連用形=で. The construction is called 連用中止. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67999/45489) for example. So the sentence means the above two sentence combined with *and*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no explicit 'all' in Japanese, though it is perhaps legitimately inferred from context:

...[and they] are only (*or* nothing but) cheerful companions, [so] I feel confident.

More simply, で is the -te form of the copula だ, compare

愉快な仲間ばかり[に囲まれて]頼もしいぜ。

where we have the -te form of 囲まれる.