# can で particle be used to say "and"

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-と, particle-で, conjunctions

I saw some example sentences where the で particle was used to say "and", can't you just use "と" or "し"? Why was で used?

Comment: Probably the following helps [How do you formulate the 連用中止 with 形容動詞 (な adjectives) and 名詞 (nouns)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Japanese, で is used as the conjunctive (basically, "`[VERB]` and...") conjugation of the basic copula ("to be" verb) だ.

Since だ means "is", で then means "is, and".

Examples:

- 電車【でんしゃ】は便利【べんり】**で**、毎日【まいにち】乗【の】ります。
  The train **is** convenient, **and** I use it every day.
- フェラーリは車【くるま】**で**非常【ひじょう】に高【たか】い。
  A Ferrari **is** a car, **and** it is extremely expensive.
- 私【わたし】は人間【にんげん】**で**、空【そら】を飛【と】ぶことはできません。
  I **am** a human, **and** I cannot fly in the sky.

Meanwhile, と just means "and" when listing things, and includes no "to be" sense.

- 人参【にんじん】**と**キャベツのサラダ
  a salad of carrots **and** cabbage
- 栗【くり】**と**リンゴを使【つか】ってケーキを作【つく】る
  to make a cake using chestnuts **and** apples

*(It must be lunchtime, I keep thinking about food. )*

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer